# linux curl command that can check the aws ec2 instance status check - 2/2 checks passed

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

How can I utilize the bash curl command to check the remote aws ec2 instance status so I can evaluate the response to determine the server is ready for use during cloud-init process? However, the IP address of the remote EC2 instance is pre-defined.

AWS console will display "2/2 checks passed" when the EC2 instance is ready for use, but I want to programmatically determine this without using the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI is certainly the best way if you are using bash: [describe-instance-status — AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html)

If you were to do it programmatically, you could do it like this. (You didn't mention your preferred language, so here it is in Python.)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-0c9c9b95b3523afdc'])

print ([(i['InstanceId'], i['SystemStatus']['Status']) for i in response['InstanceStatuses']])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John; CLI is the cleanest and simplest way to achieve it. anything else is a hack.

Using curl you can retrieve complete meta data of EC2 instance easily. But this won't give runtime status of ec2. Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html ..

Possible hack could be: Run apache/nginx on that EC2.. and curl on the test page of that apache/nginx. Once Ec2 is up; your apache/nginx will be also up and u will get HTTP response 200.